# groovy soapUI deserialize

Tags: java, unit-testing, groovy, soapui

Just started using soapUI and I like it a lot.

In a particular case using REST, I'm receiving serialized object.

I would like :

- to retrieve the serialized byte array and transform it into a Java object
- re-transform the java object into an XML response (using JAXB) 
  so it can be human readable.

Is this feasible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure to consider using XML serialization (e.g. [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/)) instead of binary one to avoid [version compatibility problems](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/platform/serialization/spec/version.html) before using the next solution:

1. Import your Java class to SoapUI groovy script ([as described there](http://www.soapui.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=7093)) or re-define your Java class in Groovy code with `Serializable` interface implemented:

   ```
   class Person implements Serializable { String name; int age }
   ```
2. Use `ObjectInputStream` and `classLoader` to load deserialize objects into object:

   ```
   // use your byte array variable instead of yourByteArray
   input = new ByteArrayInputStream(yourByteArray)
   // use your object variable instead of yourObject
   yourObject = null
   input.withObjectInputStream(getClass().classLoader){ ois -> yourObject = ois.readObject() }
   ```
3. Use `ObjectOutputStream` to serialize updated objects and save them to an XML response:

   ```
   output = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
   output.withObjectOutputStream { oos -> oos << yourObject }
   //save serialized data as byte array
   output.toByteArray()
   ```